# Windows partition refusing to boot after cloning and extending

Tags: windows-10, boot, logging, efi, disk-cloning

I recently bought a new, bigger and faster ssd. I needed to clone the disk and extend the windows partition, and did this with Acronis True Image, whose cloning function also happens to extend the partition automatically in just a couple of clicks. All went well, I booted from the new ssd a couple of times. Things looked right, so I decided to format my old ssd. Next reboot, the spinning dots that appear at boot stop moving after a second maybe, then I get the 0xc0000001 error with no other information except that I should use recovery media to repair.

So this is what I tried:

1. Automatic repair
2. chkdsk
3. bootrec /fixboot and rebuildbcd which in turn resulted in "access denied" and no installations found
4. mounting and formatting the efi partition, then copying data from c:\windows\boot... following various tutorials on different sites which all reported the same thing
5. Erasing the efi and msr partition and then rebuilding them, like [this](https://medium.com/@hetmansoftware/how-to-restore-the-structure-of-deleted-efi-partitions-in-windows-653a68b5c09f)
6. Doing a fresh install then swapping the windows partition with the old one, so that efi, msr, and restore are all good and new and without errors
7. Macrium Reflect windows boot fix function in the rescue media, which recognized my installation and windows version

All these always result in the same error. At this point, it can't be a problem with the efi partition like most sources seem to report. I really can't do a fresh install, it's an audio studio workstation with Steinberg Cubase installed, and hundreds of plugins and settings which I couldn't possibly recover.

Apart from your very welcome suggestions, opinions and things to try, what bothers me the most is that I can't get any clue to where the procedure is stopping, which file could be corrupted or missing... I can't find a way to get a verbose mode or a log... just the spinning dots.

All I have now is an acronis true image tib of the partition which I restored multiple times and the files SEEM to be all there and uncorrupted...

Comment: I suggest to [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: https://kb.acronis.com/content/45831

Comment: Thanks for your answers but I can't do an in-place upgrade since I can't boot into windows, while the article on the acronis site seems to refer to hardware changes, but I'm on the same system, just cloned the drive to another

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: solution is in the registry! (only EFI)

1. boot into the cloned installation but make sure to boot in safe mode! (F8)
2. login to your account
3. things look messy but use ctrl+alt+delete to start up task manager
4. open regedit (file > run new task > regedit > enter)
5. goto `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\MountedDevices`
6. look for `DosDevices\C:` and rename it to `DosDevices\O:` (for example, choose a letter that is not used)
7. if your cloned system drive is `D:` (in most cases), select `DosDevices\D:` and rename it to `DosDevices\C:`
8. now you can change your first renamed `DosDevices\O:` drive back to `DosDevices\D:`
9. start > power > reboot...
10. it works like a charm ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I was using rescuezilla, however, to do the cloning. I cloned the (SATA SSD) disk to the new larger (NVME) one, and then expanded using gparted.  Every time I tried to boot the disk I would get BSOD errors.  I tried recovering BCD and rebuilding the EFI partition etc. as noted above.  In the end, out of desperation, I tried booting the cloned disk in windows BEFORE expanding it, and it worked!  I don't really know why, but as shown in the answer above, windows might keep some sort of record of the size of the disk in the registry, so either you can make the registry edit as above, or boot the cloned OS from the new disk without changing it.  After first boot, I was able to resize the disk.